# How can I add data to a coreML file within an app

Tags: swift, coreml

I want to create a handwriting recognition app (probably using a CoreML framework but open to other suggestions). I know how to create a framework and teach it using the playground interface, but I'm wondering if I can train the framework within an app so I would ask the user to write specific words which would teach the program according to that user's handwriting.

I've looked into other OCR software such as Tesseract and SwiftyOCR, I have also tried using an existing coreML framework but they are either outdated or very inaccurate, especially considering users will have different handwriting.

Don't know if this is useful but I'm supposed to show some code, so this is the code to create the framework...

```
import CreateMLUI

let builder = MLImageClassifierBuilder()
builder.showInLiveView()
```

In the end, I hope to develop an application with a drawing interface (using a UIView) which will prompt the user to write the words or letters that appear on the screen. Later, the software should then be able to recognise their handwriting.

Thanks,
Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this WWDC Session Video. 
Sounds like, this is exactly your use case.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/704/

Comment: Alright thanks. I had a quick look at the video and it does explain the concept of creating an updatable model. I’ve just gotta work out how to do that now. Thanks